# how to send friend request on facebook using koala gem?

Tags: facebook, request, send, friend, koala

I am using rails 3 & koala-1.4.0.
After login facebook account..I want to send a invitation request to a friend but no idea how to do it? 
how to send friend request on facebook using koala gem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to send friend requests
There is, however, this dialog you can trigger: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/